# Sencha panel not collapsing correctly

Tags: extjs, panel, extjs4.1

Inside a tabpanel i have a panel with `'collapsible' = true`.

When i click on the icon to expand nothing happens. Only when i change tabs and then return to the previous one does the expand event fires and the panel expands correctly. The same strange behavior happens when trying to collapse.

I build both tab panel and the panel dynamically.

This is how i build the tab panel:

```js
    HnBSenchaUIGeneratorClass.prototype.GenTabPanel = function (modelConfigData, targetId) {    var hnb = this;


    var _layout = "auto";
    if (modelConfigData.Layout) {
        _layout = (Ext.decode(modelConfigData.Layout, true) == null) ? modelConfigData.Layout : Ext.decode(modelConfigData.Layout, true);
    } else {
        _layout = "auto";
    }


    var tabPanel = new Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        title: modelConfigData.WindowTitle || modelConfigData.Title,
        layout: _layout,
        closable: false,
        autoScroll: true,
        activeTab: modelConfigData.ActiveTab || 0,
        tabPosition: modelConfigData.TabPosition || 'top',
        listeners: {
            beforetabchange: {
                fn: function (tabPanel, newCard, oldCard, eOpts) {
                    //TODO: validar se isto não invalida ou interfere algum outro processo ou validação.
                    newCard.suspendLayout = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });


    if (modelConfigData.ObjId != undefined) tabPanel["objId"] = modelConfigData.ObjId;


    if (modelConfigData.BodyStyle != undefined) tabPanel["bodyStyle"] = modelConfigData.BodyStyle;
    if (modelConfigData.Closable != undefined) tabPanel["closable"] = modelConfigData.Closable;
    if (modelConfigData.Flex != undefined) tabPanel["flex"] = modelConfigData.Flex;


    if (modelConfigData.Border != undefined) tabPanel["border"] = modelConfigData.Border;
    if (modelConfigData.Style != undefined) tabPanel["style"] = modelConfigData.Style;
    if (modelConfigData.Height != undefined) tabPanel["height"] = modelConfigData.Height;
    if (modelConfigData.Width != undefined) tabPanel["width"] = modelConfigData.Width;
    if (modelConfigData.Defaults != undefined) tabPanel["defaults"] = modelConfigData.Defaults;
    if (modelConfigData.Margin != undefined) tabPanel["margin"] = modelConfigData.Margin;
    if (modelConfigData.Padding != undefined) tabPanel["padding"] = modelConfigData.Padding;
    if (modelConfigData.Property != undefined) tabPanel["dataField"] = modelConfigData.Property;
    if (modelConfigData.Anchor != undefined) tabPanel["anchor"] = modelConfigData.Anchor;
    if (modelConfigData.Rowspan != undefined) tabPanel["rowspan"] = modelConfigData.Rowspan;
    if (modelConfigData.Colspan != undefined) tabPanel["colspan"] = modelConfigData.Colspan;
    if (modelConfigData.Disabled != undefined) tabPanel["disabled"] = modelConfigData.Disabled;


    var obj;
    Ext.Array.each(modelConfigData.Items, function () {
        if (this.DontRender === undefined || (this.DontRender != true && this.DontRender.toString().toUpperCase() != "TRUE")) {
            switch (this.Type) {
                case "panel":
                    obj = hnb.GenPanel(this, targetId);
                    break;
                case "form":
                    obj = hnb.GenForm(this, targetId);
                    break;
                case "list":
                    obj = hnb.GenGrid(this, targetId);
                    break;
                case "CommandExecution":
                    obj = CreateObjectByCommandExecution(this, targetId);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            if (obj) {
                if (this.ObjId != undefined)
                    obj["objId"] = this.ObjId;


                var SelfDisabled = false;
                if (this.SelfDisabled != undefined) {
                    if (this.SelfDisabled == true) {
                        SelfDisabled = true;
                    }
                }
                obj.SelfDisabled = SelfDisabled;


                if (this.Disabled != undefined)
                    obj.disabled = (this.Disabled.toString().toUpperCase() === "TRUE");


                tabPanel.add(obj);
            }
        }
    });
    return tabPanel;
}
```

And this is how i create the panel:

```js
    HnBSenchaUIGeneratorClass.prototype.GenPanel = function (modelConfigData, targetId) {    var hnb = this;


    var _layout = "auto";
    if (modelConfigData.Layout) {
        _layout = (Ext.decode(modelConfigData.Layout, true) == null) ? modelConfigData.Layout : Ext.decode(modelConfigData.Layout, true);
    } else {
        _layout = "auto";
    }


    var panel = new Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        itemId: modelConfigData.ItemId,
        title: modelConfigData.WindowTitle || modelConfigData.Title,
        layout: _layout,
        closable: false,
        controlUrl: modelConfigData.ServiceURL
        //autoScroll: true
        //,border: modelConfigData.Border,
        //flex: modelConfigData.Flex
        //, bodyStyle: modelConfigData.BodyStyle //'background-color:green !important;'
    });


    if (modelConfigData.ObjId != undefined) {
        panel["objId"] = modelConfigData.ObjId;
        panel["itemId"] = modelConfigData.ObjId;
    }


    if (modelConfigData.Flex != undefined) panel["flex"] = modelConfigData.Flex;
    if (modelConfigData.BodyStyle != undefined) panel["bodyStyle"] = modelConfigData.BodyStyle;
    if (modelConfigData.Border != undefined) panel["border"] = modelConfigData.Border;
    if (modelConfigData.Style != undefined) panel["style"] = modelConfigData.Style;
    if (modelConfigData.Height != undefined) panel["height"] = modelConfigData.Height;
    if (modelConfigData.Width != undefined) panel["width"] = modelConfigData.Width;
    if (modelConfigData.Defaults != undefined) panel["defaults"] = modelConfigData.Defaults;


    if (modelConfigData.Collapsible != undefined) panel["collapsible"] = modelConfigData.Collapsible;
    if (modelConfigData.Collapsed != undefined) panel["collapsed"] = modelConfigData.Collapsed;
    if (modelConfigData.Region != undefined) panel["region"] = modelConfigData.Region;
    if (modelConfigData.Cmargins != undefined) panel["cmargins"] = modelConfigData.Cmargins;
    if (modelConfigData.MinSize != undefined) panel["minSize"] = modelConfigData.MinSize;
    if (modelConfigData.MaxSize != undefined) panel["maxSize"] = modelConfigData.MaxSize;




    if (modelConfigData.Margin != undefined) panel["margin"] = modelConfigData.Margin;
    if (modelConfigData.Padding != undefined) panel["padding"] = modelConfigData.Padding;
    if (modelConfigData.Property != undefined) panel["dataField"] = modelConfigData.Property;
    if (modelConfigData.Anchor != undefined) panel["anchor"] = modelConfigData.Anchor;
    if (modelConfigData.Rowspan != undefined) panel["rowspan"] = modelConfigData.Rowspan;
    if (modelConfigData.Colspan != undefined) panel["colspan"] = modelConfigData.Colspan;
    if (modelConfigData.Disabled != undefined) panel["disabled"] = (modelConfigData.Disabled.toString().toUpperCase() === "TRUE");


    addEvent(modelConfigData, panel);


    var modelFields = [];
    var panelFields = [];
    Ext.Array.each(modelConfigData.Items, function () {
        var aux;
        if (this.DontRender === undefined || (this.DontRender != true && this.DontRender.toString().toUpperCase() != "TRUE")) {
            if (this.Type == "form") {
                aux = hnb.GenForm(this);
            }
            else {
                aux = hnb.CreateSenchaUIObject(this, panel, modelFields);
            }
        }


        if (aux) {
            panelFields.push(aux);
        }
    });
    panel.add(panelFields);


    return panel;
}
```

Any ideas on why this is happening??

I'm using Sencha 4.1.2a.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was preventing both events.

In the creation of the tab panel i set up a listener for 'beforetabchange' where i did this: `newCard.suspendLayout = true;`

This is needed for another screen so i basically add an 'extra' var when i don't want to do the above. In the end it looks like this:

```
listeners: {
        beforetabchange: {
            fn: function (tabPanel, newCard, oldCard, eOpts) {
                if (tabPanel.enableSuspendLayout === true) {
                    newCard.suspendLayout = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```